# Drawing the diagram associated with the Second Homomorphism Theorem

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have code for a diagram that resembles the typical display associated with the Second Homomorphism Theorem in Group Theory. In the diagram, $H$ and $K$ represent subgroups of an abelian group G; so $H \cap K$ and $\mathit{HK}$ are other subgroups of G. The line between $H \cap K$ and $H$ indicates that $H \cap K$ is a subgroup of $H$, and the line between $H$ and $\mathit{HK}$ indicates that $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathit{HK}$.

I don't like the way the lines are displayed. They interfere with the nodes. I think that simply putting the nodes "over" the path (cycle) will make it presentable.  An `outer sep` of `1.5\pgflinewidth` may be appropriate.  It seems to me that `TikZ` ignored the specification `outer sep=1em`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,-2) node [blue] {$H \cap K$};
\draw (-1,0) node [outer sep=1em, violet] {$H$};
\draw (1,0) node [outer sep=1em, violet] {$K$};
\draw (0,2) node[outer sep=1em] {${\mathit{HK}}$};

\draw (0,-2) -- (-1,0) --(0,2) -- (1,0) -- (0,-2) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this? (No `outer sep` option but explicit offset positioning.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,shapes,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,-2) node [blue, below] {$H \cap K$};
\draw (-1,0) node [violet, left] {$H$};
\draw (1,0) node [right, violet] {$K$};
\draw (0,2) node[above] {${\mathit{HK}}$};

\draw (0,-2) -- (-1,0) --(0,2) -- (1,0) -- (0,-2) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{\fill}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** Another possibility, with the labels "over" the paths. No other packages needed than `tikz` itself. NB: the `\mathit` instruction in `$\mathit{HK}$` is not necessary, `$HK$` is sufficient.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[violet] (a) at (0:1) {$K$};
    \node (b) at (90:2) {$HK$};
    \node[violet] (c) at (180:1) {$H$};
    \node[blue] (d) at (270:2) {$H \cap K$};
    \draw (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- (a);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No.  See the diagram posted by egreg.

Comment: @Adelyn See my edited answer then.

Comment: Yes, that is the nicest code to draw this diagram!

Answer (score 3):

It's easier with `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=0em,row sep=3em]
& HK \arrow[dl,dash] \arrow[dr,dash] \\
H \arrow[dr,dash] && K \arrow[dl,dash] \\
& H\cap K
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what the typical diagram looks like in textbooks for abstract algebra.  In what manual is the syntax for this code described?

Comment: @Adelyn `texdoc tikz-cd` from a terminal or [this link at texdoc.net](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf)

Comment: `tikz-cd` is `beamer` compatible? I'm trying to do this in a presentation and it's giving an error

Comment: @Croos You need to pass `tikzcd` the option `ampersand replacement=\&` and use `\&` in the body instead of `&`. Otherwise, declare the `frame` environment to be `fragile`.

Answer (score 2):

A `pstricks` solution, with the `psmatrix` environment, from pst-node``:

```
\documentclass[pdf]{amsart}
\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

\psset{nodesep=2pt, linewidth=0.5pt, rowsep=\baselineskip, colsep=0.333em}
\[ \begin{psmatrix}
  %% nodes:
  & HK\\
  H && K \\
  & H ∩ K
  % arrows
  \ncline{1,2}{2,1}\ncline{1,2}{2,3}
  \ncline{3,2}{2,1}\ncline{3,2}{2,3}
  \end{psmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]